# Understanding vs Just Translating, when Porting

Tags: java, c++, porting

I am porting a project from C++ to Java and this thing keeps bothering me.
That I am not able to understand 100% the code, and sometimes I need
to compromise and just translate it to Java without understanding what it does.
Please let me know your thoughts on this, how you deal with it? I guess
you can't know it all, and maybe that's OK?

Thanks for any advices for this first-time porter :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to 100% understand the code to port but you should understand 100% what the code is trying to do. That way you can write unit and integration tests along the way as you are porting making sure that everything works as expected. It's also a good opportunity to understand C++ by writing a unit test for the C++ code, then write a Java unit test, then port it. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 4):

How do you hope to produce working code if you don't understand what it is doing?  Java and C++ can have subtle differences in the way similar looking code works.  I think you really need to take the time to fully comprehend what the code is doing rather than copy & pasting in to Java and fixing the syntax differences.